# Is there a way to fetch data every second in NextJS with getServerSideProps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, get, fetch-api

Are there any ways to fetch API data in NextJS with SSR(getServerSideProps) every second?
So that the client will make every one second a request to the server to get the latest API data.

Any ideas?

```
export const getServerSideProps = async () => {
  const res = await fetch(
    "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=100&page=1&sparkline=false"
  );

  const filteredCoins = await res.json();

  return {
    props: {
      filteredCoins,
    },
  };
};
```

EDIT:
This is in my index.js file.
I still need to return the `filteredCoins` from the component.

EDIT2:

So i tried this:

```
setInterval(() => {
  async function fetchCoins() {
    const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/v1/coindata");
    const filteredCoins = await res.json();

    return {
      filteredCoins,
    };
  }
}, 1000);
```

With this api route:

```
export default async function coindata(req, res) {
  const apiData = await fetchData();

  res.status(200).json({ data: apiData });
}

async function fetchData() {
  const resp = await fetch(
    "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=100&page=1&sparkline=false"
  );

  const data = resp.json();

  return data;
}
```

Comment: Why not use Websockets?) I doubt you need this data server side

Answer (score 1):

The way you have it currently set up you will need to reload the user browser every second. Instead, you should make an API route, and query that API route from the front-end, via `setInterval`, the API route can have almost identical code to your `getServesideProps` but instead of returning an object, it will send back the data with the response.
Learn about next.js API routes in [the docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction)

Comment: You mean that i create an API route wich fetches the api data and from my frot-end i target my api route?

Comment: I tried it, but i dont know how i can parse the data into my front-end. I seems that next doesn't know `filteredCoins`

Comment: I edited my question, woul'd you have a look on what's wrong?

Comment: It should all work however, front-end code requires more work. You should use `useEffect` to initiate fetch to the API. Also, `api.coingecko` supports CORS , so you don't even need to call your backend, you could query their API directly from the browser.

Comment: The problem is, I dont know how to use this data in my FE, it can't find the data/i can't access them.

Comment: Basically, I just don't know how to do it all.